# Assert Response Payload of Zip File

Tags: java, spring

In my application, I'm combining many files into a single zip file via `java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream` API, but I want to know how to write an effective unit test of the zip file.

At first I began with a "Test.zip" in my test/resources and compared the generated to the expected by comparing bytes, but this doesn't work. The bytes are retrieved from a `HttpServletResponse` (in the case of the test `MockHttpServletResponse`)

How can I test the zip contains proper file signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to compare their content. After getting ZIP file, unpack it and compare that you have the same amount of files, they have the same names and finally files's contents are the same.

Comment: I've considered this, but I was trying to avoid it :-)